# How do I Customize the 'Top Panel'?

Tags: 14.04, panel, customization, gnome-panel

I would like add some Files\Programs to Top Panel as shown below

[image: Hand Down Arrow]

[image: Sound Top Panel menu]

When I Click on that Icon (Hand), it should show my customized add-on Files\Programs Ex: Calculator,Dictionary, Units etc., just like Speaker Icon do.

How to Customize it & should run on start-up like default programs?

Is there any tools or any Programs\Scripts are available to achieve that?

Please Do help?

Comment: Top Panel? You mean the Launcher?

Comment: I mean  it should run like Weather-indicator, Brightness Indicator etc., apps @Zacharee1

Comment: Oh. I think you'd need to write your own program to have an indicator applet there.

Comment: Unfortunately, you would have to write your own indicator applet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ClassicMenu Indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/) for application menu.

For adding files/folders you can use [autokey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) and use this [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571605/how-to-open-a-window-using-autokey/656962#656962) to the open the particular folder and make sure you **☑** the option "show in notification menu"

Comment: Is Autokey is available for Ubuntu 14.04 ? @Dhiya

Comment: @Sridhar  Yes. Autokey is available for Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Code to Download Autokey? Because In that link, it is mentioned for Upto 12.04 @Dhiya

Comment: @Sridhar https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/autokey-gtk/  The latest version is 0.90.4-1. Autokey is available for Ubuntu 14.04